# Angularjs and change metatags to support SEO for different view if HTML5=true router is used

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angularjs for client side and dustjs & Nodejs at server side for my SPA based site. I need to add `<meta>` tags in `<head>` section to support the SEO. I am also using `HTML5=true` routing approach therefore my URL doesn't have #. Since I am using `HTML5=true` routing therefore I can take one of following two options to implement the SEO.

1. Change the metatags by emitting the event from View Controller and trap it in global controller and update the metatags. This approach is mentioned in the following post.
   [AngularJS and meta tags in SPA mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424881/angularjs-and-meta-tags-in-spa-mode)
2. Since SEO will use absolute URL with # therefore I can use my dust.js + nodejs and change the metatags as per the URL.

Both approaches can meet the my requirement, however I am not sure which one is best. I am thinking to go with server side approach i.e. #2 as it will simplify my code however not sure what problem I can face in future.

Please advice.

Note: I am using prerender.io to serve the pages for Search Engine.

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience doing this.
My implementation was on client side and I also used prerender.io.

From my experience - start with variant #1 (anyway it is good to show correct titles for user)... for a first time(until highload, or if you content can be cached). Also it is quite easy to implement, and you have no logic duplication between server and client...

But it has drawbacks: prerender is slow and unstable(notice: I am not talking about saas from prerender.io, it is about my own server).

So, likely later you will decide to implement variant #2 as addition for #1 or as replacement for prerender, but it is more complicated since you will need to duplicate some logic serverside.

About my implementation:

I have a service, to store meta tags information:

```
angular.module('....')
  .factory('seoParams', function ($rootScope) {
    var projectName = '....';
    var states = [];
    return {
      title: projectName,
      description: '',
      keywords: '',
      properties: {},
      canonical: false,
      prerenderStatusCode: 200,

      enter: function () {
        states.push({
          title: this.title,
          desctiption: this.desctiption,
          keyworwds: this.keyworwds,
          properties: this.properties,
          canonical: this.canonical,
          prerenderStatusCode: this.prerenderStatusCode
        });

        this.title = projectName;
        this.desctiption = '';
        this.keyworwds = '';
        this.properties = {};
        this.prerenderStatusCode = 200;
        this.canonical = false;
        return this;
      },

      exit: function () {
        var data = states.pop();
        _.assign(this, data);
      },
      setTitle: function (title) {
        this.title = title;
        return this;
      },
      setTitlePart: function (title) {
        this.title = title + ' ~ ' + projectName;
        return this;
      },
      setDescription: function (description) {
        this.description = description;
        return this;
      },
      setKeywords: function (keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
        return this;
      },
      setCanonical: function (canonical) {
        this.canonical = canonical;
        return this;
      },
      setProperty: function (name, value) {
        this.properties[name] = value;
        return this;
      },
      appendProperties: function (properties) {
        _.assign(this.properties, properties);
        return this;
      },
      replaceProperties: function (properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
        return this;
      },
      setStatus: function (status) {
        this.prerenderStatusCode = status;
        return this;
      }
    };
  });
```

Controller to actually update meta tags:

```
angular.module('....')
  .controller('SeoCtrl', function ($scope, seoParams, FB_APP_ID, TWITTER_SITE) {
    $scope.seoParams = seoParams;
    $scope.fbAppId = FB_APP_ID;
    $scope.twitterSite = TWITTER_SITE;
  });
```

and view:

```
<head ng-controller="SeoCtrl">
  <base href="/"/>
  <title ng-bind="seoParams.title"></title>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{fbAppId}}">
  <meta ng-if="twitterSite" name="twitter:site" content="{{twitterSite}}">
  <meta name="description" content="{{seoParams.description}}">
  <meta name="keywords" content="{{seoParams.keywords}}">
  <meta
      ng-repeat="(property, content) in seoParams.properties"
      property="{{property}}"
      content="{{content}}"/>
  <meta name="prerender-status-code" content="{{seoParams.prerenderStatusCode}}">
  <link ng-if="seoParams.canonical" rel="canonical" href="{{seoParams.canonical}}" />
  <meta name="fragment" content="!">
  ...
</head>
```

next thing I have is onEnter  and onExit callbacks for ui-router:

```
onEnter: ['seoParams', function (seoParams) {
  .....
  seoParams
    .enter()
    .setTitle(title)
    .setDescription(description)
    .setKeywords(keywords)
    .appendProperties({
      'og:type': 'website',
      'og:title': title,
      'og:description': description,
      'og:url': promoUrl,
      'og:image': imageUrl,
      'og:site_name': '....',
      'twitter:card': 'summary_large_image',
      'twitter:title': title,
      'twitter:description': description,
      'twitter:image:src': imageUrl,
      'twitter:url': promoUrl,
      'twitter:domain': '....'
    });
}],
onExit: ['seoParams',function (seoParams) {
  seoParams.exit();
}]
```

If you want, you can use it from controller, like following:

```
seoParams.enter().setTitle(title)....
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){ seoParams.exit() });
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about <title> which is related to functionality. I will try client side implementation now.

Comment: @Bogdan Savluk where do I insert the onEnter and onExit callbacks? thanks!

Comment: it is in state definition object when defining new state in ui-router `$stateProvider`